# Mapshaper exporting to .json not .geoJSON

Tags: geojson, mapbox, json, mapshaper

For my Mapbox maps, I am trying to simplify my .geoJSON linestrings using [Mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org) prior to importing into [Mapbox Dataset Editor](https://studio.mapbox.com/datasets/).

My problem is when I export from Mapshaper, despite selecting Export -> GeoJSON, the resulting file is a .json file, not .geoJSON. This .json file cannot be imported by Mapbox (even if the extension is changed from .json to .geojson)

How do I export to .geoJSON from Mapshaper or convert the .json to .geoJSON?

Comment: Exported file from Mapshaper is GeoJSON, when selected as export type. Please edit your question post some of your file that is supposed to not be GeoJSON.

Comment: I agree the Mapshaper export radio button says "GeoJSON" but in fact the exported file is a json file, not geojson. You can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTfpQ2cG9CU) (at 1:25 and again at 1:55) how the author clicked "GeoJSON" but the output file has a .json extension

Comment: Extension is not important, but content is, and the content is definitely GeoJSON. There is nothing wrong with `.json` extension, since GeoJSON is JSON.